# Is it possible to send more apps to review at once in App store?

Tags: ios, app-store

we have a lot of similar apps on iOS and we would like to know if its possible to send them all to review to App store, when we create new version?
Basically we are looking for something like Android's Android-publisher.

Thank you

Comment: This is outside the scope of Stack Overflow - please review [ask].

Comment: You can probably automate that with the [App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/) and tools like [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools).